# Retrieve inactive clients by LINQ

Tags: database, linq, client, orders

I have a problem with my code. I want to retrieve all the inactive clients(that have no orders) from last week. 
This is my information from database.
[information in database picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZTop.png)
Below is my code in LINQ, but it does not return anything.

```
DateTime daysBeforeToday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
var queryCount = context.Orders.Select(x=>x.ID).Count();
var query = (from o in context.Orders
where o.OrderDate >= daysBeforeToday
select new { CustomerName = o.CustomerName, ID = o.ID } into Customers
group Customers by Customers.CustomerName into pg
where queryCount == 0
select pg.Key);
return query.ToList();
```

Please advice. Thank you

**UPDATE**
I found this SQL statement that works:

```
SELECT CustomerName, MAX(OrderDate) as LastOrderDate
FROM Orders 
GROUP By CustomerName
having MAX(OrderDate) < dateAdd(day,-7, GetDate())
```

but when I convert in LINQ it fails. What I did wrong?

```
DateTime daysBeforeToday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
var queryMax = context.Orders.Select(x=>x.OrderDate).Max();

var query = (from o in context.Orders
            select new { CustomerName = o.CustomerName, Date = o.OrderDate } into Customers
            group Customers by Customers.CustomerName into pg
            where queryMax < daysBeforeToday
            select pg.Key);

return query.ToList();
```

Comment: what do you mean by this condition `where queryCount == 0`?,  `queryCount` is always greater than zero.

Comment: I wanted to bring the customers with 0 orders from that period, but I know that the logic is not good

Comment: try this : `DateTime daysBeforeToday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);

var query = (from o in context.Orders   
   group o by o.CustomerName into pg
   where pg.Max(x => x.OrderDate) < daysBeforeToday
   select pg.Key);
return query.ToList();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the comment, The `Max` should be calculated for each grouped customer, like the following code:

```
DateTime daysBeforeToday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);

var query = (from o in context.Orders           
            group o by o.CustomerName into pg
            where pg.Max(x => x.OrderDate) < daysBeforeToday
            select pg.Key);

return query.ToList();
```

I hope you find this helpful.